# An empty list is generating when I tried to find the roots of transcendental equation using NSOLVE function

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation P which is dependent on ω and γ, and I am trying to find the roots of ω for different value of γ. I have written a small module to carry out this task, but the output of the module is showing empty.

```
    Y = 2*^11;
    ρ = 7850;
    aa = 0.1*0.1;
    Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
    sd1 = Subdivide[0.001, 0.5, 300];
    sd2 = Subdivide[0.55, 2, 300];
    sd3 = Subdivide[2.2, 5, 50];
    sd = Flatten[{sd1, sd2}];
    L1=4;
    lbar = L1*sd;
    P = 1/γ^4 aa^2 (Iyy^2 Y^6 (17.033 aa^2 + 
            121.171 aa Iyy γ + 56.7964 Iyy^2 γ^2) + 
         Iyy Y^5 (-1.01106 aa^3 + 
            aa^2 Iyy (-46.8109 - 15.3405 γ) γ + 
            aa Iyy^2 (-160.727 - 64.3873 γ) γ^2 - 
            9.20748 Iyy^3 γ^4) ρ ω^2 + 
         Y^4 (0.0117278 aa^4 + 
            aa^3 Iyy (2.06068 + 0.910598 γ) γ + 
            0.373165 Iyy^4 γ^6 + 
            aa Iyy^3 γ^4 (26.0561 + 6.63437 γ) + 
            aa^2 Iyy^2 γ^2 (30.4847 + γ (24.8741 + 
                  4.07576 γ))) ρ^2 ω^4 + 
         aa Y^3 γ (aa^3 (-0.0154297 - 0.0105624 γ) + 
            Iyy^3 (-1.05601 - 0.179254 γ) γ^5 + 
            aa Iyy^2 γ^3 (-4.942 + (-2.56299 - 
                  0.279973 γ) γ) + 
            aa^2 Iyy γ (-0.960215 + (-1.09499 - 
                  0.241934 γ) γ)) ρ^3 ω^6 + 
         aa^2 Y^2 γ^2 (aa^2 (0.00488883 + (0.00819891 + 
                  0.0028063 γ) γ) + 
            Iyy^2 γ^4 (0.200292 + (0.0692493 + 
                  0.00567345 γ) γ) + 
            aa Iyy γ^2 (0.155664 + (0.112826 + 
                  0.016619 γ) γ)) ρ^4 ω^8 + 
         aa^3 Y γ^4 (Iyy γ^2 (-0.00630883 + (-0.00304845 - 
                  0.000336771 γ) γ) + 
            aa (-0.000792547 + (-0.000844803 - 
                  0.000192771 γ) γ)) ρ^5 ω^10 + 
         aa^4 γ^6 (0.0000321207 + (0.0000228257 + 
               3.90636*10^-6 γ) γ) ρ^6 ω^12);
    sd1 = Subdivide[0.001, 0.5, 300];
    sd2 = Subdivide[0.55, 2, 300];
    sd3 = Subdivide[2.2, 5, 50];
    sd = Flatten[{sd1, sd2, sd3}];
    lbar = L1*sd;
    sol[i_] := 
      Module[{root}, P = P /. γ -> lbar[[i]]; 
       s1=NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < ω < 2000]; 
       s2 = Flatten[ω /. s1];   
       s3 = Surd[(ρ*aa*s2^2*L1^4)/(Y*Iyy), 4]; s4 = s3/(2 π); 
       root = s4; Return[root]];
    nonbeta = Table[sol[i], {i, 1, Length[lbar]}];
    nonbeta1 = nonbeta[[All, 1]]
```

Comment: `L1` isn't defined, I think.

Comment: if I do it manually say gamma=0.5 and extract the roots it is matching with my finite element solution. The moment I put a loop on the module my solutions is varying.

Comment: I have given a value of L1=4

Comment: `NSolve` inside `Module` can find solutions for `ω`, what is `s1` in further substitution? And what is `Length[γ]`, `γ` is not defined as a vector?

Comment: I have updated the  code now

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot`shows the possible solutions

```
ContourPlot[P == 0 , {γ, 0, 20}, {ω, 0, 2000},MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> {γ, ω}]
```

[image]

The solutions can be evaluated with

```
Table[{γ, ω} /. NSolve[{P == 0,0 < ω < 2000}, { ω}], {γ, lbar}]//Flatten[#, 1] &;
(*{{0.004, 698.236}, {0.004, 1158.71}, {0.0106533, 698.226},{0.0106533,1158.55}, {0.0173067, 698.216},...}*)
```

Comment: I don't think `Evaluate[P]` does anything in your use of `NSolve`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  Thanks, it was a codetesting relict...

Answer (score 1):

Even Solve does the job.

```
sol = Solve[{P == 0, 0 < \[Omega] < 2000, 
                     0 < \[Gamma] < 20}, {\[Omega]}]
```

You get 8 solutions for omega as a function of gamma. (Two are only defined in the little gap near gamma=11.)

```
Plot[Evaluate[\[Omega] /. sol /. \[Gamma] -> g], {g, 0, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thread@Hue[.8 Range[0, 7]/7], PlotRange -> All]
```